# AS400 PCOMM LOOP

Tags: database, vbscript, ibm-midrange

I wish to create at macro loop in PCOMM AS400 VBscript.

The loop must repeat until a designated number is reached and skip

every other number or (step 2) Example: 11 to 273  or 10 to 272

In the ten digit line of code, only the three digit part of the number must change each time; 61106(011-273)AA

There is more to the macro before and after but, all would be repeated each time the above is the only number I need to be variable.

Any help in creating a working for next/loop in VBscript would be appreciated.

I have already researched tried and failed to get this to work.
ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.

```
    `

PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

REM This line calls the macro subroutine
subSub1_

sub subSub1_()
autECLSession.autECLOIA. WaitForAppAvailable

autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
+
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys For XXX = 011 To 273 Step Two "61106XXXAA"


autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[ENTER]"

Next

End Sub
```

Script has been shortened to highlight the area in question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to send an `[enter]` for each value. I'm sure the software you are using will have a manual, but I'm working with Windows' VBScript so there might be some syntactic or function availability differences to your platform.

`LeadingZeroes` is there to make sure you always have 3 characters.

The [`For ... Each Step`](https://ss64.com/vb/for.html) statement needed to be outside your repeated send key statement.

The [`&`](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-operators.html) is the string-concatenation operator which allows you to build your 10-digit code.

```vb
Sub subSub1_()

    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

    autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"

    For XXX = 11 To 273 Step 2
        x = LeadingZeroes(XXX, 3)
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys  "61106" & x & "AA"
        autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[ENTER]"
    Next

End Sub

Function LeadingZeroes(value, width)
    LeadingZeroes = Right(String("0", width) & CStr(value), width)
End Function
```